# How can I see my community if I'm unauthorized user?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, community-builder, access

I already made public access. I've also read documentation "Give Guests or Unauthenticated Users Access to a Community". But I think I still do something wrong.

How can I make access free for everyone?

My settings for access for guests. What I missed?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: What happens when you try to access?

Comment: I see nothing. Just empty page.